# How to publish a KTable output to a specific Kafka Topic?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to write my very first practice application using Kafka Streams to count the number of words in the topic. However, I think I am referring to old API, as at the end of lambda functions I want to put the output of KTable to a topic, but I do not see any such method.

The code I was referring used a method `to()` but I think there is no such method now. I see `toStream()` but do not know as to how to use it to put a message to a specific output topic.

Can someone have a look as this should be pretty basic.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,"streams-starter-project");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"earliest");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,Serdes.Short().getClass());


        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        //1- Stream from Kafka
        KStream<String, String> wordCountInput = builder.stream("word-count-input");
            //2 - map values to lowercase
            KTable<String,Long> wordCounts = wordCountInput
                    .mapValues(textlines -> textlines.toLowerCase())
                    //or mapValues(String::toLowercase())
                    //3- flatMapValues split by space
                    .flatMapValues(lowerCasedTextLine-> Arrays.asList(lowerCasedTextLine.split(" ")))
                    //4- Select key to apply a key and discard old key
                    .selectKey((ignoredKey,word)-> word)
                    //5 - groupBy key before aggregation
                    .groupByKey()
                    //6- count occurences finally
                    .count();

        **wordCounts.to**
```

Comment: You should use `table#toStream()#to("topic")` -- You may also want to consider to disable record caching: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Can you explain why we should use toStream().to() instead of using Materialized "internal changelog topic" directly?  Is it so we can change the topology later without affecting consumers?  Or is there a more subtle reason?

Comment: Yes, that is the main (and only reason). Keep things decoupled.

Answer (score 1):

The below code works perfectly for me:

```
    // 1 stream from kafka
    StreamsBuilder streamBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
    
    KStream<String, String> wordInputStream = streamBuilder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC);
    
    // 2 Map values to lowercase
    KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = wordInputStream.mapValues(value -> value.toLowerCase())
    // 3 flat map values split by space
    .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split(SPACE)))
    //4 select key to apply as key
    .selectKey((key, value) -> value)
    //5 group by key before aggregation
    .groupByKey()
    // 6 count
    .count(Named.as("Counts"));
    
    wordCounts.toStream().to(OUTPUT_TOPIC); // here OUTPUT_TOPIC was used from string constant
```

using kafka-streams 3.0.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following count method:

`KTable<K, Long> count(Materialized<K, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> var1);`

So in your code:

```
KStream<String, String> wordCountInput = builder.stream("word-count-input");
        //2 - map values to lowercase
        KTable<String,Long> wordCounts = wordCountInput
                .mapValues(textlines -> textlines.toLowerCase())
                //or mapValues(String::toLowercase())
                //3- flatMapValues split by space
                .flatMapValues(lowerCasedTextLine-> Arrays.asList(lowerCasedTextLine.split(" ")))
                //4- Select key to apply a key and discard old key
                .selectKey((ignoredKey,word)-> word)
                //5 - groupBy key before aggregation
                .groupByKey()
                //6- count occurences finally
                .count(Materialized.<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("your-topic-name")
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                        .withValueSerde(Serdes.Long()));
```

Materialized generate state store (RocksDB by defauult) and synchronized to kafka topic "yournameapp-your-topic-name-changelog". Then you can create kafka consumer to read that topic, or create interactive querys to get the data of the ktable.

Comment: There is no reason so pass in a `Materialized` parameter. It's not related to.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax thx for your comment. I considered that solution, but question says "I want to put the output of KTable to a topic" so I think my answer fits the question.

Comment: The point is, that the changelog topic will be created independent of the `Materialized` parameter. Second, it's considered an internal topic and it's "better" to create a proper output topic (compare my comment on the question itself).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code.

```
workCounts.toStream().to("word-count-output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config);
streams.start();
```